# Windows not booting when chosen in GRUB interface

Tags: linux, windows, grub

I have a desktop with 3 disks :

```
Disk 1 : windows 11
Disk 2 : Fedora 38
Disk 3 : data
```

The linux disk is the first boot option.

The grub menu shows me the fedora + windows options but when I chose windows it restart the pc and since the linux disk is the first boot option it shows me the same grub menu again, so it loops.

How can I fix grub so that when I chose the windows line on the gurb menu it boots into windows instead of restarting the PC ?

Comment: Change the boot order temporarily to Windows and, if it boots correctly, change back to Fedora (Grub), boot Fedora and run the command to update Grub. If Windows can't boot directly then obviously it won't boot when chainloaded from Grub and you have to correct it with Windows installation media.

Comment: For reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/what-is-the-equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-and-centos-systems